# Is there any easy method to create drop shadows in Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

1. I cant get Image borders "fake shadows" with a transparent gradient
2. Working with Codename One's CSS is a random mess (padding and so on, as the outer shadow is actually a kind of inverted cropping "inner shadow")
3. Effects.dropshadow - the same (tons of code, needs the final sizes of the component on the screen and does not support other shapes than rectangles)

As drop shadows are very fashionable these days (Material Design and so on) there has to be an easier way ... (something without counter balancing every component with padding, etc.)

Comment: Can you share an example (CSS snippet + Screenshot) of the results you're getting with the CSS plugin.  I may be able to either (1) identify a bug in the css lib or (2) suggest a modification that will get you what you want.